# Updated php5-fpm, can't use socket anymore

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm, socket

Earlier today, I updated packages on one of my servers. One of those packages was an update to php5-fpm, which seems to have broken my ability to utilize `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

**Disclaimer**: I only recently started using Linux; I don't *fully* understand what's going on here.

I've reviewed lots of other questions but have no been able to find answer to my issue, which is that I get a 502 Bad Gateway error if I try to use `php5-fpm.sock` instead of passing to `127.0.0.1:9000`.

Here are some details that seem relevant based off of other questions:

- My `php5-fpm` process **is** running.
- My `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file has `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
- My server block has `fastcgi_pass = unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
- `php5-fpm.sock` **does** exist in `/var/run/`.

When upgrading php5-fpm, it asked me if I wanted to overwrite my www.conf. I checked the diff and the only change between the maintainer's file and mine was that the maintainer's had `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` set as the default.

After selecting to overwrite it and finishing upgrading php5-fpm, I opened up `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and changed listen to `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, like it had been set beforehand. I then restarted php5-fpm, and then nginx, in that order.

I now get a 502 when visiting the domain and am at a complete loss. If I change `listen` in www.conf and `fastcgi_pass` in my host file to `127.0.0.1:9000`, everything works perfectly. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS, if that matters.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the owner of the php5-fpm.sock file by using ls -l /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

I believe you'll find it set to root and your web server runs as www-data. Further, the permissions in the www.conf are 0660 which means only root will have permissions.

You can uncomment the lines related to the sock user and set it to www-data and restart the php5-fpm service

Comment: You were right, thanks for your insight. I uncommented `listen.group`, `listen.user`, and `listen.mode`. That fixed it, and I'm now able to pass `fastcgi_pass` to `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. What is the different between this user/group and the `user` and `group` variables earlier in `www.conf`? I would think the "Unix user/group of processes" (as they are labeled) would be a logical choice for php5-fpm to use to create the socket.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-nginx-and-php-fpm-setup-for-php-fpm) the unix user and group are the owners of the site files and not the owner or the process file. Hope this helps!